# Program completes but I receive this warning: "too much output to process"

Tags: python, excel, process

I am currently in the process of creating a Excel Filtering Tool using Python and PyQt. The goal is to be able to filter out GPA of students and output certain result based on the cutoff for their grade level and GPA.

When I run the program on my IDE PyCharm The program runs the filtering and runs to completion and I am able to output the filter result, however during the process i receive the error "too much output to process". I tried to build my program outside the IDE using Cx_freeze and when i run the exe version The program will only run a couple lines of the excel file through the filter then stop. I believe this is due to my previous error i would get in the IDE that theres too many lines of text inside the excel file.

My excel file has about 6000 rows of data and 16 columns.

This is a part of the code:

```
def filterCommand(self):
        global workbook2
        wb = xlrd.open_workbook(defaultName)
        sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
        workbook2 = xlwt.Workbook()
        worksheet2 = workbook2.add_sheet('Test')

        styles = xlwt.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour yellow')

        #Then get values of each column. Excuse first item which is header
        term = sheet.col_values(0)[1:]
        ids = sheet.col_values(1)[1:]
        fnames = sheet.col_values(3)[1:]
        lnames = sheet.col_values(2)[1:]
        gender = sheet.col_values(4)[1:]
        zero = sheet.col_values(5)[1:]
        acadgroup = sheet.col_values(6)[1:]
        acadprog = sheet.col_values(7)[1:]
        status = sheet.col_values(9)[1:]
        strtlevel = sheet.col_values(10)[1:]
        acaplan = sheet.col_values(8)[1:]
        credits = sheet.col_values(12)[1:]
        GPA = sheet.col_values(11)[1:]
        fiucredits = sheet.col_values(13)[1:]
        transferc = sheet.col_values(14)[1:]
        takeprgrs = sheet.col_values(15)[1:]
        type1 = sheet.col_values(16)[1:]
        email1 = sheet.col_values(17)[1:]
        type2 = sheet.col_values(18)[1:]
        email2 = sheet.col_values(19)[1:]
        phone = sheet.col_values(20)[1:]
        ethnicgroup = sheet.col_values(21)[1:]
        firstgen = sheet.col_values(22)[1:]

        newrow = sheet.nrows
        header = []
        for i in range(0, 1):
            rowheader = sheet.row_values(i)
            header.extend(rowheader)
            print header[0]
        for ind, key in enumerate(header):
            worksheet2.write(0, ind, key)

        row = 1
        for index, row_data in enumerate(credits):
            grade_level = row_data
            gpa_level = GPA[index]
            # row_data[index] = float(credits)
            # worksheet2.write_column(row, 0, row_data)
            # Check for rows that match the filter.
            print gpa_level
            print grade_level
            if grade_level >= 90.0:
                print fnames[index] + '\t' + lnames[index] + '\t' + ": Senior"
                if gpa_level >= 3.2:
                    #Do Filtering
                    print '\t' + "Allowed"
                    row += 1
                    pass
                else:
                    print '\t' + "not allowed"
                    # worksheet2.set_row(row, None, None, {'hidden': True})

            elif (grade_level <= 89.0 and grade_level >= 60.0):
                print fnames[index] + '\t' + lnames[index] + '\t' + ": Junior"
                if gpa_level >= 3.0:
                    #Do Filtering
                    print '\t' + "Allowed"
                    row += 1
                    pass
                else:
                    print '\t' + "not allowed"
                    # worksheet2.set_row(row, options={'hidden': True})
            elif (grade_level <= 59.0 and grade_level >= 30.0):
                print fnames[index] + '\t' + lnames[index] + '\t' + ": Sophomore"
                if gpa_level >= 2.7:
                    #Do Filtering
                    print '\t' + "Allowed"
                    row += 1
                    pass
                else:
                    print '\t' + "not allowed"
                    # worksheet2.set_row(row, options={'hidden': True})
            elif grade_level < 30.000:
                print fnames[index] + '\t' + lnames[index] + '\t' + ": Freshmen"
                if gpa_level >= 2.5:
                    #Do Filtering
                    print '\t' + "Allowed"
                    row += 1
                    pass
                else:
                    print '\t' + "not allowed"
```

this is what my excel sheet looks like:

[image: excel3]

how could i go about fixing this issue because im not sure why it works in the IDE but not in the .exe

Answer (score 0):

Excuse. A question in return: Do You every heard of ISO:OSI stack?
For example this: [ISO:OSI stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).

Most probable the avaible code pages did change. You get an error caused by that kind of problem stuff. In the IDE the stack is controlled. In the run environment it is not.

This article might already solve Your problem:
[Python socket programming and ISO-OSI model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458087/python-socket-programming-and-iso-osi-model)

Other type of problem might be RTF-8. If this is not interpreted the correct way Excel control sequences inside your spreadsheet act as virusses or are simply cause of overflows.

[Export Pandas data frame with text column containg utf-8 text and URLs to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875238/export-pandas-data-frame-with-text-column-containg-utf-8-text-and-urls-to-excel)

An very old rule for Python programmer is aviod native Microsoft formats. You are better off using text base formats direct relating to CODECs like RTF-8. That situation did only change little recently due to change in mircosoft formats polcies.

Hope that helps.